# Where do the pieces numbered 4255629 go in the Death Star (set 10188)

Tags: building, star-wars

I just finished up the Death Star set, and while it comes with the usual smattering of leftover pieces, I've got two pieces numbered 4255629 (shown below) that never got used.  I've scanned the manual three times now and just can't see where I missed the pieces.

Were they just included for decorating at my leisure, or is there a specific page that shows where to use them?

The piece looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10188-1) lists only one such element, and [peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/10188-1) lists one, with one as extra. It's typical for LEGO to include duplicate of very small parts, and 1x1 tiles usually fit the bill. So there should only be one actually used in the set. I have no clue where though, just send me one and I'll try to find it :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is one going in the small blue trolley on page 4. These pages don't show parts inventories, and the part is partly hidden, so it's very easy to overlook.

The other one is an extra, as explained in comment.

Comment: Thanks for offering me this opportunity to browse the manual (and yes, even if it's on page 4, I didn't find it at first so I had to go through it all) and drool at a great set I'll probably never have :-)

Comment: Wow, that's a great catch.  That's funny, the figures were the one place I didn't look because they didn't have inventories, and that's what I was looking at.  Thanks again!

Comment: I wasn't expecting it there either - just got lucky.